# как записать числа розделенные пробелом из динамических textbox в массивы чисел?

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms, textbox

Необходимо считать числа из textBox и записать их в массив
i.stack.imgur.com/k9N1y.png

```
public void CreateRowsTextBox()
        {
            TextBox[] textBox2 = new TextBox[height_of_nonogram];
            for(int i = 0;i < height_of_nonogram; i++)
            {
               textBox2[i] = new TextBox();
                textBox2[i].Text = "Row " + (i + 1);
                Point p = new Point(200, 30*i);
                textBox2[i].Location = p;
                this.Controls.Add(textBox2[i]);

            }
        }
```

Comment: так и считываете my_mas[j] = textBox2[i].Text;

Comment: @TEA а как учитывать пробелы?

Answer (score 0):

//ваш предыдущий код

```
  int[] massiv = new int[100];
  for(int i = 0;i < height_of_nonogram; i++)
       {
```

либо TryParse http://www.quizful.net/interview/csharp/parse-tryparse-difference

```
massiv[i]  = Int32.Parse(textBox2[i].Text);

       }
```

Comment: System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format' @TEA

Comment: так переделайте под свой код,я тут пример написал